# Create a list using SVG and HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, list, svg

The question is a follow-up to my previous question here:
[Creating a git commits graph style list with css/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609549/creating-a-git-commits-graph-style-list-with-css-js)

Basically, can I have a list in a git-style, which would include SVG, so that when I zoom in it wouldn't lose it's quality?

While a basic `:before` and `:after` does work, I was wondering if you can improve this somehow?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SVG version of Git Commits Graph.
I have created this SVG graphic with using of **Path, Circle and Text SVG** elements.

You can change the fill and stroke colors as your like.

**Demo Here:**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Git-Commits" width="350" height="450" viewBox="0 0 350 450">
  <path class="svg_img" id="Outline" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="2" d="M57.016 43.048v360l108-79v-210z"/>
  <circle id="List-Item6" cx="165.016" cy="324.048" r="15.62" fill="#4B5AA8" stroke="#121241"  stroke-width="2"/>
  <circle id="List-Item5" cx="164.877" cy="253.1" r="15.62" fill="#4B5AA8" stroke="#121241" stroke-width="2"/>
  <circle id="List-Item4" cx="164.877" cy="185.48" r="15.62" fill="#4B5AA8" stroke="#121241" stroke-width="2"/>
  <circle id="List-Item3" cx="165.016" cy="114.048" r="15.62" fill="#4B5AA8" stroke="#121241" stroke-width="2"/>
  <circle id="List-Item2" cx="57.016" cy="403.048" r="15.62" fill="#4B5AA8" stroke="#121241" stroke-width="2"/>
  <circle id="List-Item1" cx="57.016" cy="42.107" r="15.62" fill="#4B5AA8" stroke="#121241" stroke-width="2"/>
  <text transform="translate(192.016 121.814)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="23.257">
 List item 1
  </text>
  <text transform="translate(192.016 192.815)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="23.257">
 List item 2
  </text>
  <text transform="translate(192.016 258.815)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="23.257">
 List item 3
  </text>
  <text transform="translate(192.016 331.815)" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="23.257">
 List item 4
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I'm not very familiar with SVG drawings and you're a life saviour! :)  
Cheers!

Comment: @Amo, glad to hear that! Good luck! :)